# What does "[^<]" in a sscanf evaluation expression mean?

Tags: c, scanf

Googling "sscanf reference" or various other sscanf search terms brings up plenty of available references regarding the C sscanf function.  Many of these references contain explanations of the available tokens that can be used in format string.

I'm looking through another developers code (who no longer works with our company) and I see in a format string that he has multiple tokens that looks like `%15[^<]`.  I know that the `%15` portion of the token is taking 15 characters from the reference string and storing them in a string pointer.  What I can not find is documentation that explains the function of the `[^<]` token.

I've looked through multiple reference pages and I can't find a reference to a token like this.  Maybe I'm just clicking on the wrong links but what does this mean?  Furthermore, is sscanf (and other cstdio functions with format strings) more robust than what traditional documentation outlines?  If so, is does anyone have a link to more thorough documentation?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference you should be checking is [the ISO standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), particularly section `7.19.6.2`.

For your particular case, it's matching fifteen characters that aren't `<`.

Answer (score 1):

The first reference I found ([here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)) sure includes it. Search the page for `[`.

Brackets are used, much like in regular expressions, to express groups of characters that match. If the first character is a ^, the group is inverted. So `[^<]` will match any character except for the less-than symbol.

Comment: You should note that some applications try to use range expressions like `[^a-z]`, as in regular expressions, but the C standard (nor POSIX) does not define a behavior for this usage and it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

That token matches everything but "<". Is it some kind of XML or HTML parser perhaps?

If you're on a platform other than Windows it's propably in the man page for scanf. Otherwise, I advise you to install cygwin. :)

Comment: @paxdiablo I thought it was easier to write "other platforms than Windows", than to list all possible OS's that have man pages. ;-)

Comment: @paxdiablo BeOS should definitely contain man pages, CP/M should come with printed documentation, as for z/OS I'm not sure.

Comment: FYI, this is for an embedded system.

Comment: @RLH Doesn't matter, the standard libraries are the same (hopefully).